# TinyMCE use <div align="center"> instead of <div style="text-align: center">?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE 3.2.5 and by default when you click the center align button it uses an inline style `<div style="text-align=center">`. I would like tinyMCE to use 
`<div align="center">` instead of the inline style.

I know setting inline_styles: false in the configuration works. But I would like to use inline styles for everything but alignment.

How would I go about changing this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  The 'align' attribute is deprecated: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#adef-align

Comment: Because HTML that validates is *so last year*.

Comment: I am using the YUI resize library inside tinyMCE and it does not function correctly when using text-align:center.

Comment: i think this is a great reason to NOT USE TinyMCE. Those types of editors are more trouble than they're worth. And chances are your users DO NOT want to look at html. The most advanced thing they should need to do is bold, italicize, and underline.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        'formats' : {
        'alignleft' : {'selector' : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', attributes: {"align":  'left'}},
        'aligncenter' : {'selector' : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', attributes: {"align":  'center'}},
        'alignright' : {'selector' : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', attributes: {"align":  'right'}},
        'alignfull' : {'selector' : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', attributes: {"align":  'justify'}}
    }
})
```

Comment: HAHA. Took 3 years, but that answer works perfect. - Although I don't remember the original reason for this question.

Comment: I might just be using a different version of TinyMCE, but I had to change "alignfull" to "alignjustify".  Besides that, this worked great for me!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Write your own plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aCreate_plugin/3.x) and set the align as you wish.